# How to create a Log with listBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I'm creating a webapp in c# using visual stdio 2008.

In the page there's a button that starts a quite long (about 1 min) processing.
During this i would like to show what the program is doing in a listbox in the same page but I don't know how to do it beacuse when the process start the page is continuously refreshing so the listbox is always empty even if in the code there are many `ListBox.Items.Add("..")`.

Hope you can help me.
(p.s. sorry for my bad english,I'm italian)

Comment: You could simply change the ListBox to be a textbox (unless for some unknown reason it must be a listbox) and add messages to a Session['ProcessMessage'] and make the textbox.text = Session['ProcessMessage'].ToString()

Comment: Consider using a `BackGoundWorker`

Answer (score -1):

May be your page load is taking time for other reasons, but not sure.

```
public static void WriteLog(string Error)
{
    using (StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(filePath + "Log.txt", true))
    {
        logfile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + " -@: " + Error);
        logfile.Close();
    }

}
```

Use this function to log.

Call this function in Page load

```
WriteLog("Comments");
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.